# AzerothCore login suddenly wants authenticator code

Tags: mysql, azerothcore

I've been running AC fine for a while now, but tonight it suddenly started asking for an authenticator code when I log in. I haven't made any changes to the AC accounts DB, merely updated to the latest version.

Things I've tried:

- Made sure I'm accessing the correct server - can see login attempt on my AC instance.
- I've tried deleting the Cache/WTF folders, with no effect.
- Tried a new client in a different directory, which didn't help.
- Added new accounts - when I try logging in to the brand new accounts, the Wow client asks for the authenticator code again.
- had a look in the auth DB - apparently a token_key field handles 2FA, but can't see it in my DB, or I'd try deleting it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Same problem here, I make an clean install in a virtual machine and work, then I do the same in a real pc and want the 2 steps authentification...

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug that was introduced recently but it has been fixed on revision `983d4b57713688e37705e26afa4c5bf4c14d3099`, [updating your AzerothCore to the latest version](https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/Update) should fix it.